# Simplifying boolean logic expressions to DNF and CNF (in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, logic, boolean-logic, agda

I understand that there are generally-accepted algorithms for reducing a given boolean-logic expression to CNF or DNF. I've found a few websites about this sorta thing, but nothing that I can really use to build a Haskell program around it.

This isn't homework, nor am I asking for someone to write me code - I'm just looking for some kind of resource that I can follow to help me build my functions.

It seems to me that I have to define a datatype `Exp` which deals with `Or Exp Exp`, `And Exp Exp`, *etc.*, *etc*. and then build the standard 'rules' (De Morgan's, *Modus Ponens*, *Modus Tollens*, what have you) to use to repeatedly apply to to the `Exp` until I reach a point where I'm not getting any further.

(As I've been playing around with Agda *etc.*, I've tended to write everything in Haskell before translating it to Agda. So yeah, if you're more familiar with expressing anything in Agda, then I'm going to understand that too.)

Comment: You have the right idea. If your `Exp` is only `And` or `Or` then you actually only need one of De Morgan's laws (on that choice depends whether you reach CNF or DNF). What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you add more operations, you'll only need to rewrite them with `and, or, not`. It doesn't really add complexity. Also, I confused something about the rules. You need both De Morgans. You need one distribution instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what description there is. You match each constructor,  call your `toCNF` on the children and combine the results. Obviously, `toCNF (And a b) = And (toCNF a) (toCNF b)`. You also need to match `Not (And a b)` and `Not (Or a b)` for De Morgan. Matching `Or` is the most interesting part, of course, but it's just distribution. If you find this challenging, I suggest first writing a function which applies De Morgan until all negations are of literals. It's simpler, but basically the same.

Comment: You can try to implement e.g. [Tseitin transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation). There are plenty of websites explaining how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use the nice [hatt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hatt) package for it. It has [API](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hatt-1.5.0.3/docs/Data-Logic-Propositional-NormalForms.html) for converting to NNF, CNF etc. This is some sample code:

```
import Data.Logic.Propositional
import Data.Logic.Propositional.NormalForms

a = Variable (Var 'A')
b = Variable (Var 'B')
c = Variable (Var 'C')
d = Variable (Var 'D')

expression = Conjunction a (Disjunction b (Conjunction c d))
```

And then you can play up with the `expression` in `ghci`:

```
λ> expression
(A ∧ (B ∨ (C ∧ D)))
λ> toCNF expression
(A ∧ ((B ∨ C) ∧ (B ∨ D)))
```

I would suggest you to look on the source of the package as it's not very complicated.